# SharpSVN: Recursivly delete "missing" files?

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

Is there a way to recursively `svn delete` files in a working copy that have been moved/deleted outside of SVN with SharpSVN?

I have a task that runs periodically to commit a directory exactly as it is, but I need files that have been removed to be marked as `deleted` instead of `missing`.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably handle this scenario like:

```
using (SvnClient c1 = new SvnClient())
using (SvnClient c2 = new SvnClient())
{
    c1.Status(@"F:\working-copy",
        delegate(object sender, SvnStatusEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.Status == SvnStatus.Missing)
              c2.Delete(e.FullPath);
        });
}
```

(Untested code. Feel free to fix typos)